# Protecting Firestore without requiring authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So currently in the project we have a collection of documents that don't require authentication to be read. They are write/update protected, but everyone can read.

What we are trying to prevent is that someone looks at the firebase endpoints and somehow manages to scrape the entire collection in json format (if this is even possible). The data is public, but I want it only to be accessible from our website.

One of the solutions we could think of was SSR (we are already using Next.js), but implementing SSR just for this reason doesn't seem very enticing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Let me rephrase a little bit.
From what you see in the network tab, is it possible to forge/create a request to Firestore and get the entire collection instead of just the 1 document that was intended?

Comment: so it is required that the application retrieves the documents in bulk but you want to prevent bad actors to retrieve that data? This sounds something like bot-detection, why do want to make it difficult to scrape the data?

Comment: Yes, pretty much bot detection. We don't want anyone to be able to scrape our data and use it for their own application. The application never retrieves more than a handful of documents at a time. What I'm worried about is that someone can just send 1 request and download our entire collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution in your case is SSR. I know, it could sound as not enticing, but well, let's reason on when we should use SSR, then. In your use case, there is an important requirement: security. I think this is already a strong enough reason to justify the usage of SSR.

Also, creating an ad hoc service account for the next.js app, and securing the  data with custom rules that allow the read of your data only to that service account, would only improve the overall security level.

Last: reading the data server side should make your site work a little faster, even if it would be difficult to notice, because we are talking about milliseconds. Notice that your page, as it is now, will need to be loaded, before the request to Firebase could be sent. This is adding a small delay. If the data is loaded server side, the delay is not added.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately SSR is probably the way to go. From what you see in the network tab, is it possible to forge/create a request to Firestore and get the entire collection instead of just the 1 document that was intended?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's why it is preferrable to implement the read server side or via a function/rest api, but that would just add an other layer to the architecture and make it slower

Comment: Will App Check be able to prevent this?

Comment: Nope. As per documentation, App Check does not work on Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

Comment: Alright, I think we'll end up doing SSR then. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to forge/create a request to Firestore and get the entire collection instead of just the 1 document that was intended?

If you want to limit what people can request from a collection, you're looking for security rules. The most common model there is some form of [ownership-based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access) or [role-based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access), but both of those require some way of identifying the user. This could be [anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) (so without them entering credentials), but it'd still be a form of auth.

If you don't want to do that, you can still control how much data can be gotten through the API in one go. For example, if you in the security rules [allow `get` but not `list`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations), the user can only request a document once they know its ID. Even if you allow list, you can [control in rules what queries are allowed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

Comment: This is very interesting, I'll definitely take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach could be writing a Cloud Function that retrieves this public data using the admin SDK. Then, you could set a rule that nobody can read those documents. This means that only your Cloud Function with the admin SDK will have access to those documents.

Finally, you could set up AppCheck for that specific Cloud Function, this way, you ensure that the request is coming from your client app only.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

Comment: I tried something similar, however the cloud functions simply weren't fast enough. I've been looking around and I'm trying to figure out of it is even possible to only from what you see in the network tab, forge the requests to firestore and retrieve the collection.

Comment: That's true, it could be more slow than getting data directly from your client. That's (I think) one of the tradeoffs to consider when you want something to be fully controlled with your backend programs. BTW, are your Cloud Functions located in the same region as your Firestore service?